# How to know crash happened in particular thread from stack trace like apple does?

Tags: ios, crash

I am creating Crash developer portal using swift Perfect, there I have to group similar Crashs, for each crash I will assign address_id it calculated using `symbol address = stack address - load address + slide`,now the problem is each stack contains around 20 lines is there any way to find where crash happened in particular line in stack like apple does it for xccrashpoint even though crash happened in system libraries

Ex: Crash

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018554443c objc_msgSend + 28
1   Foundation                      0x0000000186cb9610 empty + 72 (NSMapTable.m:57)
2   Foundation                      0x0000000186c03b18 -[NSConcreteMapTable dealloc] + 108 (NSMapTable.m:62)
3   Foundation                      0x0000000186c49610 -[NSISEngine dealloc] + 392 (NSISEngine.m:1779)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018fb70138 -[UIView _layoutConstraintCleanup] + 508 (UIView.m:3870)
5   UIKit                           0x000000018f89e578 -[UIView dealloc] + 184 (UIView.m:3884)
6   UIKit                           0x000000018fa0c500 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 700 (UIViewController.m:2340)
7   *******Framework                0x00000001018631e4 -[ViewController dealloc] + 160 (ViewController.m:536)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185c66a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185c73698 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016 (inline_internal.h:2500)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186292544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186290120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2012 (CFRunLoop.c:3111)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001861afe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
13  GraphicsServices                0x000000018805cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
14  UIKit                           0x000000018f90467c UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
15  ********                        0x00000001004b01b0 main + 88 (main.m:14)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185ccc56c start + 4
```

Apple xccrashpoint:
[Apple xccrashpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEdzg.png)
Edit:
I am able group crash which are happened in my app.

Comment: What have you tried ?  Please read and follow the following docs before posting your next question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What's a crash dev site?

Comment: Caleb I have updated my question please check

Answer (score -1):

try to see this post , you have to check dSYM file to analyze the crash info 
[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: I am able to symbolicate the crashes, but for portal I have to group similar crashes, like apple does(xccrashpoint).